# How to use Where() extention method to find greater than array fields

Tags: c#

I have string array "_from" that has some values.
I have a Query field named "query" that read values from table.
this query have a field named "path" that type is varchar(10).
I want to find all values in query where path field have greater than _from values.
I can use where extention method in for loop but I want to use "OR condition" not "AND".
I mean I want to find any Item that greater than first field Or second field of _from Array.

this is sample code of mine.

```
string[] _from = new string[2] { "01-01-002", "02"};
query = query.Where(t=> _from.Any(n=>n <= t.Path));
```

Comment: how you want to compare? like length of string?

Comment: "where path field have greater than `_from` value" - could you, please, explain this passage? Does it mean "there's an item in `_from` such that its length >= `Path.Length`"? Or "`Path` is longer (`Length`) than any item in `_from`"? Or anything else? Please, provide, an example of the desired output

Comment: No, not length. I Want compare to values for example" first field of _from is "01-01-002". Assume Path field in query have values like "00, 01, 01-01-003, 01-01-020"
I expect to return " 01-01-003, 01-01-020" 
as SQL server return these results

Answer (score 0):

Try this linq :

```
        string[] query = { "00-00-000", "01-01-001", "01-01-001", "01-01-003", "01-01-020" };
        string[] _from = { "01-01-002", "02" };

        var temp = query.Where(q => _from.Where(from => Compare(q,from) ).Any()).ToList();
```

and make the "Compare" method as follow :

```
bool Compare(string query, string from)
    {
        string[] s1Array = query.Split('-');
        string[] s2Array = from.Split('-');
        bool isLarger = false;

        int loopLength = s1Array.Length <= s2Array.Length ? s1Array.Length : s2Array.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < loopLength; i++)
        {
            if( int.Parse( s1Array[i] ) > int.Parse(s2Array[i]))
            {
                isLarger = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isLarger;
    }
```

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
No, not length. I Want compare to according values for example" first field of _from is "01-01-002". Assume Path field in query have values like "00-00-000, 01-01-001, 01-01-003, 01-01-020" I expect to return " 01-01-003, 01-01-020" as SQL server return these results.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
string[] query = { "00-00-000", "01-01-001", "01-01-001", "01-01-003", "01-01-020" };
string[] _from = { "01-01-002", "02" };

string valueToCompareTo = _from.Min();

foreach (string s in query.Where(q => string.Compare(q, valueToCompareTo) > 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

> 01-01-003
>   01-01-020

- This assumes dictionary order for your strings, which is typically what SQL Server would do.
- If you want to find all items from `query` that are larger than at least one item in `_from`, it is enough to compare to the smallest item in `_from`. (I.e. the lexicographically minimal value).